# Computing divisors on nonsingular curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is problem 8.2 from Fulton's Algebraic Curves. Let $X = C = V(Y^2 Z  - X(X-Z)(X- \lambda Z)) \in \mathbb{P^2}, \lambda \neq 0,1$. Compute div$(x)$ and div$(y)$, where $x = X/Z$, $y = Y/Z$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511950/calculating-the-divisors-of-the-coordinate-functions-on-an-elliptic-curve