# Why does $\frac{X - aZ}{Z}$ have a double pole at the point $(0 : 1 : 0)$ and not just one (Divisors)?

Tags: elliptic-curves

If I have an Elliptic Curve E and the function $\frac{X - aZ}{Z}$, I would have expected the divisor to be, defining a point $P = (a,b)$ and $-P = (a,-b)$, $div(f) = [P] + [-P] - [\infty]$.

Instead the correct solution would be $div(f) = [P] + [-P] - 2[\infty]$.

Where does this double pole come from? It would have made sense if the denominator would have been $Z^2$, but it is not.

Comment: The [Crytpo question 55342](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/55342) "I cannot understand the concept of a divisor for an elliptic curve" has an answer which explictly answers your question. Essentially a rational function has the same number of zeros as poles.

Comment: Thank you, the answers explain why $\infty$ has to be a pole but they do not explain why there are two.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/511950/14699

Comment: Looks like this question really is a duplicate of the question you mentioned... Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rational function $f(x) := x - a$, for example, expressed in homogeneous coordinates is $f(X/Z) = (X - aZ)/Z$ which has a single zero in the numerator and a single pole given by the denominator. Thus a simple zero and a simple pole always appear together. In general, when there are multiple zeros "up to multiplicity", there will be an equal number of poles "up to multiplicity".

For example, if $f(x) := (x-a)(x-b)$, when it is expressed in homogeneous coordinates, then it becomes $$f(X/Z) = (X - aZ)(X - bZ)/Z^2$$ which has two simple zeros in the numerator **and** one double pole given by the denominator. Thus, $div(f) = [a] + [b] - 2[\infty].$ The key idea is that both zeros and poles can have "multiplicity" and this has to be taken into account so that they balance each other in all cases. When two simple zeros merge they become one double zero, and so on.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question.